# Есть ли в Python возможность нахождения пути в словаре до определенного значения?

Tags: python, словари

Работаю с API. 
Есть два словаря.
Первый:

```
my = {
  'id1': {
    'p1': 'Sloane Stephens',
    'p2': 'Polona Hercog',
    'p1_odds': 1.2,
    'p2_odds': 3.8,
    'isfound': False
  },
  'id2': {
    'p1': 'Belinda Bencic',
    'p2': 'Donna Vekic',
    'p1_odds': 1.8,
    'p2_odds': 2.1,
    'isfound': False
  }
}
```

И второй который приходит по апи:

```
{  
'sportId':123,
'last':216699817,
'league':[
    {  
     'id':3742,
     'name':'WTA French Open - R3',
     'events':[               
        {  
           'id':9999999999999,
           'starts':'2019-05-31T11:30:00Z',
           'home':'Sloane Stephens',
           'away':'Polona Hercog',
           'rotNum':'8705',
           'liveStatus':0,
           'status':'I',
           'parlayRestriction':2,
           'parentId':994897148,
           'altTeaser':False,
           'resultingUnit':'Sets'
        },
        {  
           'id':994906276,
           'starts':'2019-05-31T11:30:00Z',
           'home':'Veronika Kudermetova (+1.5 Sets)',
           'away':'Kaia Kanepi (-1.5 Sets)',
           'rotNum':'8705',
           'liveStatus':0,
           'status':'I',
           'parlayRestriction':2,
           'parentId':994897148,
           'altTeaser':False,
           'resultingUnit':'Sets'
        }
     ]
    },
    {  
     'id':3735,
     'name':'WTA French Open - Doubles',
     'events':[  
        {  
           'id':994977085,
           'starts':'2019-05-31T11:30:00Z',
           'home':'L Hradecka / A Klepac',
           'away':'S Kenin / A Petkovic',
           'rotNum':'15571',
           'liveStatus':0,
           'status':'O',
           'parlayRestriction':2,
           'altTeaser':False,
           'resultingUnit':'Regular'
        },
        {  
           'id':995164497,
           'starts':'2019-05-31T12:45:00Z',
           'home':'M Puig / S Rogers',
           'away':'S Hsieh / B Strycova',
           'rotNum':'15575',
           'liveStatus':0,
           'status':'I',
           'parlayRestriction':2,
           'altTeaser':False,
           'resultingUnit':'Regular'
        }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Мне нужно проверять есть ли во втором словаре(отчете апи) значение в home, которое есть в первом словаре. В данном случае это будет `"Sloane Stephens"`.

Если оно есть, то нужно присвоить его id в данном случае это `"9999999999999"`

Я понимаю как это сделать через много циклов, когда мы проверяем каждое значение из второго словаря в таком же цикле в первом словаре по каждому значению.

Но может быть есть способ проще, рациональней?

Можеть быть можно лучше организовать мой первый словарь?

Про путь я имел ввиду, что может быть если бы мы нашли последовательный список из ключей то смогли бы по нему достать значение из `'id'`

тут это будет `['league'][0]['events']['id']`

Зная, что в `['league'][0]['events']['home']` у нас нужное значение

Answer (score 0):

Может быть имеет смысл реорганизовать ответ API таким образом, чтобы значения из `'home'` были ключами словарей. Тогда вы можете проверять наличие имен из словаря `my` в ответе API и если совпадение найдено, то что-то с этим делать.

```
events = {event['home']: event for event in api_resp['league'][0]['events']}
```

Получим:

```
{'Sloane Stephens': {'id': 9999999999999,
  'starts': '2019-05-31T11:30:00Z',
  'home': 'Sloane Stephens',
  'away': 'Polona Hercog',
  'rotNum': '8705',
  'liveStatus': 0,
  'status': 'I',
  'parlayRestriction': 2,
  'parentId': 994897148,
  'altTeaser': False,
  'resultingUnit': 'Sets'},
 'Veronika Kudermetova (+1.5 Sets)': {'id': 994906276,
  'starts': '2019-05-31T11:30:00Z',
  'home': 'Veronika Kudermetova (+1.5 Sets)',
  'away': 'Kaia Kanepi (-1.5 Sets)',
  'rotNum': '8705',
  'liveStatus': 0,
  'status': 'I',
  'parlayRestriction': 2,
  'parentId': 994897148,
  'altTeaser': False,
  'resultingUnit': 'Sets'}}
```

Теперь можно проверять наличие имен из `my` в `events`:

```
for key, value in my.items():
    name = value['p1']
    if name in events:
        event_id  = events[name]['id']
        print(name, event_id)

# Sloane Stephens 9999999999999
```

Но имейте в виду, что, например:

```
print('Sloane Stephens' in events)
# True
print('Veronika Kudermetova' in events)
# False, потому что ключ - 'Veronika Kudermetova (+1.5 Sets)'
# И, возможно, придется предварительно избавиться от (+1.5 Sets)
```

Учитывая, что вам, возможно, придется избавляться от лишних символов в значениях из `'home'` перед тем, как использовать их в качестве ключей, то может быть будет проще (хотя и медленней) сделать так:

```
for key, value in my.items():
    for event in api_resp['league'][0]['events']:
        if value['p1'] in event['home']:
            print(value['p1'], event['id'])
```